# Scrum is methodology or framework?

Tags: scrum, methodology

I am confuse about scrum .it is methodology or Framework?.
I want to use scrum for development but i want to develop scrum tool but i am confuse scrum is methodology or framework?

Comment: Framework generally refers to _code_ that provides consistent infrastructure to do something (serialization, inversion of control, communications). I'm not sure how one might think scrum was that...

Comment: @Telastyn There is also the concept of a process framework, something that gives you the pieces of a process that you can assemble and tailor to define how your team or organization builds software.

Comment: [Scrum](https://www.scrum.org/Resources/What-is-Scrum) is a framework for working working with a team on a project.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by develop a scrum tool?

Comment: @ThomasOwens - and how is that different from a methodology? I mean sure, there may be pieces of a process there to help implement the methodology, but in my experience those are so mutable as to be meaningless.

Comment: @Telastyn A methodology is exactly how you build software - your processes, inputs, outputs, work products, activities, and so on. Some people refer to the methodology used as the team's process.

Comment: Scrum is an Agile methodology.

Answer (score 4):

Sources such as [Scrum.org](https://www.scrum.org/Resources/What-is-Scrum), [Scrum Alliance](http://www.scrumalliance.org/why-scrum), and even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) do refer to Scrum as a framework. Something to consider, though, is that Scrum is at the project management level, not at the product development level. It defines activities and artifacts to run a project and manage work, without any specifics as to how to go about designing, building, and testing software - those pieces will need to come from something else, although there are many common characteristics of the [Agile methodologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development).

However, although many sources call Scrum a framework, a purist would say that if you aren't doing everything that Scrum calls for, you aren't doing Scrum. That would imply that it's more of a methodology, a complete package that's meant to be used as-is (see [ScrumBut](https://www.scrum.org/ScrumBut) for more on this). However, in reality, there are very few process methodologies that will work for everyone as-is, and some level of tailoring or adjustment is needed.

Comment: Excellent Answer.  Also a purest may also note there are no true Scotsman :)